# The command `luarocks config` gives errors

Tags: windows, lua, luarocks

I installed luarocks-2.2.1-win32 from here:

```
https://keplerproject.github.io/luarocks/releases/
```

and the installation was simple. There is a .bat file that does it all. But unfortunately, the rocks that are downloaded are not recognized by LUA. I checked my LUA install by issuing

```
luarocks config
```

and get this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua: C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\luarocks.lua:3: module 'luarocks.command_line' not found:
    no field package.preload['luarocks.command_line']
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\lua\luarocks\'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\lua\luarocks\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree\share'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree\share\lua\5.1\luarocks\command_line.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree\share\lua\5.1\luarocks\command_line\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree\share\lua\5.1'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\systree\lib\lua\5.1\luarocks\command_line.dll'
    no file 'C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Roaming\LuaRocks\share\lua\5.1\luarocks\command_line.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\Stefan\AppData\Roaming\LuaRocks\lib\lua\5.1\luarocks\command_line.dll'
    no file '.\luarocks\command_line.dll'
    no file '.\luarocks\command_line51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\luarocks\command_line.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\luarocks\command_line51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\luarocks\command_line.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\luarocks\command_line51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\loadall.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\loadall.dll'
    no file '.\luarocks.dll'
    no file '.\luarocks51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\luarocks.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\luarocks51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\luarocks.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\luarocks51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\loadall.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\loadall.dll'
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'require'
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\luarocks.lua:3: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

Anyone have experience with installing LUArocks into windows?

Comment: Add the path to `luarocks` directory as your environment variable: `LUA_PATH`

Comment: tnx. How can i give you credit for a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\lua\luarocks\'
```

indicates that your `LUA_PATH` file is incorrect, as it produced a filename without the name of the module you were looking for (normally it would look something like `C:\Program Files (x86)\LuaRocks\2.2\lua\luarocks\command_line.lua`.

In the `LUA_PATH` and `LUA_CPATH` variables, the character `?` expands to the module name, so for instance if `LUA_PATH` is `c:\mymodules\?.lua`, trying to require module `foo.bar` will open `c:\mymodules\foo\bar.lua`.

When adding a path to `LUA_PATH`, it is customary to add two variants per directory, like this for a hypothetical `c:\mymodules`: `c:\mymodules\?.lua;c:\mymodules\?\init.lua`. When you do this for the actual directories where your Lua modules reside, Lua will find them.

(Still, the `luarocks.bat` script installed by LuaRocks should have been configured out-of-the-box with the directories where the installer installed them. Which flags did you use when launching `install.bat`?)